Bootstrap Selectpicker Not Displaying old() Value in Laravel Form
I am using Laravel's Form::select along with Bootstrap's selectpicker in my form. My dropdown is supposed to display the old value (retrieved using old() function) after form validation fails. However, the selected value is not showing correctly when selectpicker is applied.
Here’s my current code:
{!! Form::select(
    'edit_promotionId',
    $promotions,
    old('edit_promotionId'),
    [
        'class' => 'form-control selectpicker',
        'data-live-search' => 'true',
        'id' => 'edit_promotionId'
    ]
) !!}


Without selectpicker, the old value is displayed as expected. However, when I add selectpicker, the selected value is not shown.
What I tried:

Ensured that old('edit_promotionId') returns the correct value.
Inspected the generated HTML, and the selected attribute is set correctly on the corresponding <option> tag.
Called $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh') in my JavaScript, but it still doesn't work.

Question:

How can I ensure the old() value is displayed correctly in the dropdown when using Bootstrap selectpicker? Am I missing any additional steps to synchronize selectpicker with the old() value?

